# LINQ insert ignoring default values, what about stored procedures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Unfortunately I found out that LINQ ignores the default values when inserting rows. The work around is to change the `Auto Generated Value` property of each column in the DBML to `True`

This is fine and dandy for tables that only have a few of these columns, but i have a table that has 20+ that need to default.

Before I spend the time creating a stored procedure, will a stored procedure even respect/use the default values?

**EDIT: LINQ ignores the default values when inserting rows**
This means if I have 10 columns, and I only give values for the first 3 columns with my LINQ insert, the remaining 7 columns will have a value of null instead of the default values defined by the table

Comment: **LINQ ignores the default values when inserting rows** Means ?

Comment: @Xander what are you referring to when you say `domain`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any SQL insert will respect the default values as long you don't explicitly pass in NULLS for the column values.

This will work fine in a stored procedure.